# Docker container (mysqld-exporter) cannot access other docker container (mysql) on one server

Tags: mysql, docker, prometheus

In my (simplified) setup, I have 2 Servers, A and B (and others, which behave like B), and my local machine. On each of the servers, a `mysql`-database and a `mysqld-exporter` prometheus-exporter should be running as docker containers. The containers are not linked, but communicate via the network over the opened port.

The servers are managed by a tool, and therefore contain the same versions of the programs with the same configs, like ports, docker network name. The difference are hostnames, ip addresses and other server-specific stuff.

The problem is, that the `mysqld-exporter` on server `A` produces the log message: `level=error msg="Error pinging mysqld: dial tcp SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:3306: getsockopt: connection timed out" source="mysqld_exporter.go:268"` (where SERVER_IP_ADDRESS is the server's ip), while the exporter on `B` works fine.

I also tried to create the container "by hand", with `docker run`, and set the `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` as environment variable, on server `A`, `B` and locally to connect to server `A`. Now, the container works and connects to server A as expected from my local machine and from server `B`, but still not from `A`. Therefore, I assume the database works fine (not overloaded).

What are reasons why the docker-container doesn't work on machine `A`? I run out of ideas what to look for.

If any necessary information is missing, please let me know!

**EDIT:**

With "by hand", I mean the docker-command `docker run -d -p 9104:9104 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="USERNAME:PASSWORD@(SERVER_URL:MYSQL_PORT)/" prom/mysqld-exporter:v0.10.0` executed in the console, which works to connect to A from B and localhost, but not A.

As explained, the server URL should also work on server A, since B and localhost use the same url to connect to the database.

Comment: How do you expose port? (Command line args, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml? Please show your configuration.) Unless you have created a network, either manually or using a docker-compose.yml, SERVER_IP_ADDRESS will be your docker-machine‘s IP.

Comment: @stoeff edited my question and tried to answer your questions. If other things are unclear please let me know!

Comment: would you please edit your post and add your docker-compose file?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi there is no docker-compose file, since I set up the whole enviroment via ansible.

Comment: Would you want to answer your question using `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi sorry, I didn't find an answer. I did a workaround by running stuff on another server (`C`), where everything worked as expected. I don't know why it didn't work on that one specific server (`A`).